# Accessibility support for Flutter app development

Tags: flutter, dart, accessibility, flutter-ios, flutter-android

How user-friendly is that app development using flutter to satisfy the accessibility checks compared to native implementations?
Can dart programming is completely satisfying assistive technologies?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Flutter myself but they have documentation on accessibility at https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility

Looks like there's a class called [`Semantics`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html) that has a lot of what you need and a short 1 min video on YouTube that talks about that class, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvtMt_DtFrQ

Comment: Yes, I tried Semantics class. How much is user-friendly compared to native Accessibility?